# odd behavior, where cout makes the program work

Tags: c++

I have two threads in C++. One thread called alarm thread runs the function `raiseAlarm()` and the other thread called print thread runs the function called `printMetrics`. At a fixed interval, `raiseAlarm` sets an atomic variable to `true`. When the variable is `true`, `printMetrics` thread, which is spinning on the value of this atomic variable, prints some data. When I run this application, nothing happens. But if I put a `cout` anywhere in `raiseAlarm`, everything works fine. Why?

```
void Client::raiseAlarm()
{
    bool no = false;
    while(!stop.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
        //cout << "about to sleep\n";
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(captureInterval));
        while(!alarm.compare_exchange_weak(no, true, std::memory_order_acq_rel))
        {
            no = false;
        }
    }
}

void Client::printMetrics()
{
    bool yes = true;
    while(!stop.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
        while(!alarm.compare_exchange_weak(yes, false, std::memory_order_acq_rel) )
        {
            yes = true;
        }

        cout << "Msgs Rcvd: " << metrics.rcv_total.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        cout << "Msgs Sent: " << metrics.snd_total.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        cout << "Min latency: " << metrics.min_latency.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        cout << "Max latency: " << metrics.max_latency.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        metrics.reset();
    }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't busy-poll using atomic variables, instead a better solution would be to use [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) signaling.

Comment: the classical sleep model introduces lot of latency in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a suggestion because I'm not so savvy with concurrency in C++, but make sure you don't forget to flush your output stream. Either stick a `cout << flush;` after all of your `cout` lines or add an `<< endl` to each one (which will automatically flush your stream).

Comment: This would be my hunch also.

Comment: Agreed. Or at least a newline somewhere.

Comment: @Jimm - It seems as though you don't have any linefeeds in your console output?  If you use std::endl, that induces an implicit flush, while sending '\n' sends a linefeed but does not flush the output.  In your case, I'd only flush at the end of the 4th line, after all of the rest had been buffered.

Comment: Nitpicking:  is `flush` a stream modifier or a method of the class?  I always used `cout.flush();`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's both and they both have exactly the same effect. :)

Comment: @phonetagger - inserting `'\n'` inserts a **newline**; the particular byte or bytes that get sent are system dependent.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Newline, linefeed, same thing.  `std::endl` == `"\n" << flush`.  My point was that I didn't see any newlines in his calls to `std::cout`, so I'm guessing that perhaps the strings returned by `metrics.~~~~~()` may have `"\n"` newlines, which do produce newlines, but don't flush `cout`.  I was only adding that `std::endl`, while also producing a newline, has the added "benefit", if one chooses to see it that way, of also flushing `cout`.

Comment: @phonetagger - no, newline and linefeed are two **different** things. A carriage return moves the output position to the beginning of the current line; a newline moves the output position down to the next line without changing the horizontal position. The two motions together make up a newline.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Your own comment illustrates the muddiness of the issue.  Let's use the terms NL, CR, and LF to represent "newline", "carriage return", and "linefeed".  Your comment says, in effect, "a CR and NL together make up a NL"!  How can CR+NL == NL?  (That was rhetorical; I'm not really asking you.)  I'm sure you meant to say "a CR and LF together make up a NL".  In C and C++, the single character '\n', guaranteed to occupy a single byte, is translated upon text-mode output to the native "newline sequence" of the platform, which ***may*** be multiple bytes.  `std::endl` is the same.

Comment: @phonetagger - sorry, mis-typed. ASCII defined values for **carriage return** and **line feed**. The latter moves the output position down to the next line without changing the horizontal position. In C and C++, the character constant `'\r'` is translated into a carriage return on output; the character constant `'\n'` is translated into whatever the system requires to start a new line.